# Using Autofac Ioc InstancePerHttpRequest with Servicestack 5.1.0

Tags: autofac

We have recently upgraded our API's (using Forms Authentication) Servicestack version 4.0.40 to latest stable version of Servicestack (V5.1.0). We use Autofac Ioc registration using InstancePerHttpRequest for API's (this is using Autofac.Integration.Mvc from Autofac.Mvc4 package).

Below code does not work anymore after servicestack upgrade.

```
this.UseAutofac(afcBuilder.Build());
```

> Error CS0012  The type 'ServiceStackHost' is defined in an assembly
>   that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly
>   'ServiceStack, Version=4.0.48.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

So we have tried alternate ways to make it work using InstancePerDependency but that is causing missing "ASP.NET_SessionId" cookie value after API authentication.

Please suggest code to get actual "InstancePerHttpRequest" work with latest ServiceStack version.

Answer (score 0):

I've already answered [this question in ServiceStack Customer Forums](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/change-in-api-behaviour-missing-asp-net-sessionid-cookie-after-servicestackupgrade/6131/4?u=mythz) but for anyone else's benefit with similar issues I'll include it below:

The issue isn't with ServiceStack or AutoFac it's with one of your dependencies which still has a binary reference to an old **v4.0.48** of ServiceStack (highlighted in the Exception). You can't mix and match ServiceStack .dlls from different versions so you would need to re-compile whichever assembly has the old binary ServiceStack reference to use the version of ServiceStack you're using.

Autofac wouldn't have a dependency to ServiceStack, it would be one of your dependencies that is registered with Autofac. You can either use an Assembly inspector like [JetBrains dotpeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) and inspect the .dll references of each dll reference in your project or comment out registrations until you find the one with the dependency.

---

Basically you're unlikely to get anywhere focusing on ServiceStack or Autofac .dll's, you need to find the `.dll` that has a reference to ServiceStack **v4.0.48** and re-compile it to use the version of ServiceStack you've upgraded to.

If you look at the dependency of [Autofac.Mvc4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.Mvc4/), you'll see it only has a dependency to Autofac. Autofac's not going to have a dependency to ServiceStack v4.0.48, one of your own .dll's is going to have the old binary reference that's causing the issue.

Comment: Thanks mythz, it was one of external package (Autofac.Extras.Servicestack) which had reference to old servicestack version. This was used to get InstancePerHttpRequest work as we can't use InstancePerLifetimeScope for API's. Can you please suggest alternate approach for Autofac implementation for API's to use with InstancePerHttpRequest  or anything similar. Tried the same and InstancePerRequest but had error Message "No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested."

Comment: @Kalyan I'm not familiar with Autofac, but I would discourage using request scope which is most of the time non optimal and a source of issues like this. Basically I'd suggest if the dependency is Thread Safe it should be registered as a singleton, otherwise register it as a transient dependency.